# Open 25+ tabs with javascript at once

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, tabs, load

I'm using javascript to open all links to images on a website. But the script stops after opening about ~25 tabs, this probably caused by Chrome. I have tried Firefox but it freezes (and so I wouldn't even dare to try it in IE). I have tried to make the script wait for 500 milliseconds between each tab, but that changed nothing besides making the script slower.

Any suggestions on how to solve this? Isn't there maybe some way to only open the next tab when the previous one is fully loaded?

```
function in_array(needle, haystack) {
    var key = '';
    for (key in haystack) {
        if (haystack[key] == needle) {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
function sleep(milliseconds) {
  var start = new Date().getTime();
  for (var i = 0; i < 1e7; i++) {
    if ((new Date().getTime() - start) > milliseconds){
      break;
    }
  }
}
var allLinks = document.links;
var allHrefs = [];
var openedWindows = [];
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < allLinks.length; i++) {
    if (allLinks[i].href.match(/\.(jpg|png|jpeg|gif|bmp)$/i)) {
        allHrefs[x] = allLinks[i].href;
        x++
    }
}
for (var i = 0; i < allHrefs.length; i++) {
    if (!in_array(allHrefs[i], openedWindows)) {
        openedWindows[y] = allHrefs[i];
        y++;
        sleep(500);
        window.open(allHrefs[i])
    }
}
```

Comment: Why did you create a sleep function when you could just `setInterval` or `setTimeout`

Comment: @Matt sounds like it's just a personal script rather than a website function

Comment: Oh god - @Jimmy's right. It's the `sleep` function that's thrashing the browser. **You must use [`setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) or [`setInterval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setInterval).**

Comment: Matt, I would probably even go as far as to pierce the website with my own frozen blood and then bury it below 5 meters of feces. But this script is just for myself.

Answer (score 3):

Since it seems like the obvious script breaker, replace your `sleep()` function and just `setInterval` or `setTimeout` your link opening functions. You could change your last loop to something like this

```
    for (var i = 0; i < allHrefs.length; i++) {
        if (!in_array(allHrefs[i], openedWindows)) {
            openedWindows[y] = allHrefs[i];
            y++;
            setTimeout(window.open(allHrefs[i]), 500);
        }
    }
```